# Filter Array if object have key false

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

Hi there I'm having small problem, I'm filtering my json on objects but actually as You will guess its does not work could you tell me what I am doing wrong ?

```
global.selection.Data.Options.filter(function (optionItem) {
return optionItem.hidden === false  })
```

Json :

```
options : [0 : {name: "some name", hidden:false}]
```

Comment: `return optionItem.hidden === false`, its not a string in the json

Comment: `return !optionItem.hidden` ?

Answer (score 1):

You are doing a type-specific comparison with `===` against string `'false'`, but you actually have a primitive *boolean* `false` in your array.

Match against a primitive boolean instead (`hidden === false`).

Comment: Actually I was Having === false but didint work also i had this as a string cuz I was even trying the stiuped things

Comment: Or just `!optionItem.hidden`.

Comment: That would match anything "falsey" (such as `undefined`, `null`, `0`, `''`), which may or may not be wanted behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing either `optionItem.hidden == false` or `optionItem.hidden === false`. As 'false' is a non-empty string hence it is truthy in javascript.

Comment: Or just `!optionItem.hidden`.